# Android app has been assigned to any possible file - should be assigned to my custom file only

Tags: android, android-manifest, mime-types, email-attachments, intentfilter

I'm trying to assign my Android app to custom file (json content) with extension "kka". 
I'd like to be able to open my app and read *.kka file in following cases:
1. *.kka as email attachment (gmail client)
2. *.kka as file stored in filesystem e.g. Downloads/ folder

My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mydomain.kka" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.kka.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.kka" android:mimeType="*/*"/>
                <data android:scheme="content" android:pathPattern=".*\\.kka" android:mimeType="application/stream-octet"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

That's the only configuration I found to be able to start my app tapping *.kka as attachment in gmail client and as file in filesystem.

The problem is that my app appears in every possible place where I want to open email attachment or file on filesystem, no matter what kind of file it is, so my KKATest app is on the list of assigned apps for e.g. XMLs, PDFs, even APKs, etc. 
It seems to ignore file extension I clearly mentioned in AndroidManifest file.

This situation takes place on Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.4, Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3 and few more.

I've read many suggestions on StackOverflow but no one solves my problem. What's wrong with my manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue. I need to open my file from both SD card as well as from email attachment. For me it was also trail and error, but this is my solution:

```
<intent-filter> <!-- Intent filter for opening files from system -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.locx" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> <!-- Intent filter for open files from email -->
            <data android:scheme="content" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.locx" />
        </intent-filter>
```

locx is my file type obviously.
BTW: I only tested with Gmail app, from other forum posts I understand that other email apps might work different.

Comment: Why just **android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"**, and not **android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"**?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as you pointed out, some email clients replace the mime type with application/octet-stream. So I ended up using an intent filter like this:

```
<!-- Filters for handling local files -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="file" android:pathPattern=".*\\.mtype" android:host="*"/>
            </intent-filter>

<!-- Filter for email apps -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/mtype"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

This will have your app handle both mtype, and octet-stream. But in the octet-stream case, it may not be actually your file, so you need to do some checking in the app. This means getting the file name, and checking the extension. For this, you can query the content provider, using the uri handled to you in the app, via the intent:

```
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(data, null, null, null, null);
int fileNameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("_display_name");         
if (fileNameColumnIndex != -1) {
    String fileName = cursor.getString(fileNameColumnIndex);
}
```

Now, there are a couple of scenarios:
If you used the gmail client, ther "_display_name" is present;
If you clicked the file, in the Downloader native app, the "_display_name" is present;
If you used the native email client, it is not present; And in this case, i prompt the user to first download the file. If he does so, and then opens the file in the email client again, it will actually open the file, and it will be handled by the first intent-filter.

Comment: What is **android:mimeType="application/mtype"**, is it a known mimeType on android?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution (almost) and the solution looks like this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mydomain.kka" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mydomain.kka.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\.kka" android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/custom-kka" android:scheme="content" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't know why entry `<data android:host="*" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern=".*\.kka" android:scheme="file" />` with one backslash ("\") instead of two ("\\") solves the issue with opening all possible files from filesystem - now my app opens only for *.kka files ...

Opening files attached to mails needs to be handled by assigning to mime-type, not file extension. I created custom mime-type `"application/custom-kka"` and ensured that during sending mail with the file there needs to be set my custom mime-type for attachment.

To do so, I put a piece of code in email composer code:

```
...
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("application/custom-kka");
...
```

which should guarantee me proper mime-type for my attachment. Unfortunately, android mail clients (gmail, generic mail client) on few devices send mails with different then mine mime-type, e.g. `"application/octet-stream;"`, `"<nothing here>;"` but not desired `"application/custom-kka;"` and my app can't identify such attachment as assigned to it.

That's the PhoneGap application, so I have also iOS version, where sending this mail with custom mime-type works perfectly and android app can recognise the attachment.

Maybe someone had such issue and could help?